# Postgreql: adding database by its files

Tags: postgresql

I have copied database folder from `data/base` and I wanted to copy them in another computer but in `pgAdmin` can't find the new database should I do something else besides copying the folder in `data/base`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

[image]
The problem is that when I try to save database from `pgAdmin` it freezes, I'm not sure if the database is corrupted or some tables.

Comment: `data/base` is not enough to restore a complete cluster. You have to copy the complete `data` but that will **only** work if the you copied the data while Postgres was stopped, the target computer uses the same operating system and the exact same Postgres version.

Comment: Have you considered using pg_dump?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa how can I use it ?

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-backup-database/

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa The problem is that when I try to save database from pgAdmin it freezes, I'm not sure if the database is corrupted or some tables. taht's why I decided to copy the whole folder of database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not sure this was actually a duplicate, as the original question was about copying a database via the file structure which none of those articles do.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa: the last duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503185/is-it-possible-to-restore-a-postgres-database-by-simply-swapping-out-some-files) covers that. But given the fact that SlimenTN just wants to backup some tables, the list of duplicates will answer that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think I spotted your edit in time, yep sounds good on that last link. :)